# Is it possible to reconstruct a finitely generated group from its category of representations?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group, and suppose $Rep_k(G)$ is its category of representations over some field (or maybe even a ring) $k$, endowed with whatever extra structure is needed --- monoidal structure, fiber functor etc. Is it possible to reconstruct $G$ from this category?

Please note that my question isn't about Tannakian reconstruction.
Indeed, Tannakian reconstruction (in the forms familiar to me) requires the tensor category to be rigid (that is, it considers only finite dimensional representations) and produces not $G$ itself, but some proalgebraic group over $k$, called $k$-proalgebraic completion. Proalgebraic completion of a finitely generated group could be trivial: for example, Tarski monster doesn't have any finite dimensional representations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are non-isomorphic (finite) groups with isomorphic group algebras over some field (Berman). So you have to cheat at some point to keep track of the group.

Comment: @YCor do you mean isomorphic over any field? Over algebraically close field of char 0, group algebra of a finite group is just direct sum of matrix algebras, so the group algebra alone indeed doesn't give much information. I have to remember, at the very least, the usual Tannakian stuff (tensor product and fiber functor).

Comment: I read "over any ordinary field"; I guess it means any field in which the order of the groups is invertible.

Comment: There are groups $G_1,G_2$ such that $\mathbb{Z}G_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}G_2$, as described here: 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/3062112

Comment: You can then tensor the group rings by any ring $R$ you like to get an isomorphism of the corresponding $R$-algebras. However, finite groups are compact groups, so we can use the Tannakian theory for compact groups (equivalently affine proalgebraic groups over $\mathbb{R}$). The key point is that we need the symmetric monoidal structure to recover the group multiplication. This doesn't affect the question as asked, because the monoidal structure was explicitly included.

Comment: You cannot recover the group from the group ring as a ring, but you can recover it from the group ring as a Hopf algebra. A Hopf algebra contains a subset of *grouplike* elements: $\{x\;|\;\Delta x=x\otimes x\}$. Over a field, the nonzero grouplike elements recover the group. Invertible grouplike elts for general nonzero ring? Alternately, Tannaka's reconstruction theorem identifies the group with the group of natural automorphisms of the fiber functor. Krein's hypotheses about dualizability are only necessary to identify a category of representations, but you assume that you have one.

Comment: What am I missing here? Isn't $t: G\to Aut(F), g\mapsto (t_V^g)_{V\in Rep_k(G)}$ an isomorphism, where $F: Rep_k(G)\to k-mod$ is the fibre functor and $t_V^g$ is $F(V)\to F(V), v\mapsto gv$ ? $t$ is easily seen to be bijective by evaluation on the regular representation. Isn't that the whole point of the Tannakian theorem that one does not need the regular representation if one has all the finite-dimensional ones?

Comment: @JohannesHahn As stated in the question, there are infinite finitely-presented discrete groups that have no finite-dimensional representations on vector spaces except the trivial rep (and the zero rep). Any finitely-presented infinite simple group, such as Thompson's groups $T$ and $V$, is like this, because any representation is faithful, and any group with a faithful representation on a finite-dimensional vector space is residually finite (Mal'cev's theorem) which contradicts the group being simple.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Actually, scratch what I just said. I think I misinterpreted your last sentence. If you mean that (for $G$ a discrete group, $k$ a field) the (non-monoidal) endmorphisms of $F : \mathbf{Rep}(G)_k \rightarrow \mathbf{Vect}_k$ correspond to elements of $kG$ by the enriched Yoneda lemma (twice), and then the grouplike elements of $kG$ are exactly those that map to monoidal natural transformations, and therefore recover $G$, then I agree that this answers the question, and if you write it as an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: @JohannesHahn That answers my question, thank you very much! Could you please write an answer so I could mark the question as closed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $F: Rep_k(G) \to k\mathsf{-mod}$ be the fibre functor. $G$ can be reconstructed from this functor and the monoidal structure as the group of automorphisms, because $t: G\to Aut(F,\otimes,k), g\mapsto (t_g^V)_{V\in Rep_k(G)}$ is an isomorphism, where $t_g^V$ is just the $k$-linear map $F(V)\to F(V), v\mapsto gv$. Because the morphisms in $Rep_k(G)$ are $k[G]$-linear maps, $t_g$ really is a natural transformation. It clearly satisfies $t_g^{-1}=t_{g^{-1}}$ so that it is a natural automorphism of $F$. By definition of the monodial structure it also satisfies $t_g^{V\otimes W} = t_g^V\otimes t_g^W$ and $t_g^{k} = id$.

$t$ is injective, because $g = t_g^{k[G]}(1)$. $t$ is surjective, because if $\tau=(\tau^V)$ is any natural automorphism of $F$ and $u:=\tau^{k[G]}(1)$, then $u$ is a unit of $k[G]$ because $\tau$ is invertible and by naturality of $\tau$ applied to the $k[G]$-linear map $k[G]\to V, 1\mapsto v$, one sees that $\tau^V = v\mapsto uv$. $u$ is not just any invertible element, it is an element of $G$, because $\tau^{V\otimes W} = \tau^V\otimes\tau^W$ and $\tau^k=id$: Write $u=\sum_g a_g g$ with coefficients $a_g\in k$ and consider how $\tau$ acts on $k[G]\otimes k[G]$. On the one hand, it is multiplication by $u$, so $\tau(x\otimes y) = u(x\otimes y) = \sum_g a_g g(x\otimes y) = \sum_g a_g (gx)\otimes(gy)$. On the other hand, it is $\tau^{k[G]}\otimes\tau^{k[G]}$, so that $\tau(x\otimes y) = (ux)\otimes(uy) = \sum_{g,h} a_g a_h (gx)\otimes(hy)$. Letting $x=y=1$ and comparing coefficients, we find $a_g a_h = 0$ for all $g\neq h$. This means that at most one of the coefficients is non-zero. The action on the trivial module $k$ is trivial so that $1=\tau(1) = u1 = \sum_g a_g$ from which we conclude that there is exactly one non-zero coefficient that it is equal to one, i.e. $u$ is a group element.

Therefore if you have the full category of *all* representations with its fibre functor and the monoidal structure, it is trivially easy to reconstruct $G$. The point of the Tannakian theory is that for certain groups knowledge of the finite-dimensional part of $Rep_k(G)$ is sufficient to reconstruct $G$.

Comment: The answer as stated seems false to me: The fiber functor functor is representable (as a $k$-linear functor) by the regular representation. So the $k$-enriched natural transformation are exactly the automorphisms of the regular representations. And there are already a lot more of these than justs $G$. A more reasonable statement  would be that $G$ identifies with the enriched & monoidal natural transformation, meaning that you also needs the monoidal structure.

Comment: Oooh. So that was what I missing! $\tau^{k[G]}(1)$ can be any unit of $k[G]$, not just a group element. I should have seen that.

Comment: I've edited my post to correct my previous argument as you suggested.

Comment: @Johannes Hahn can you expand the last part of the proof please ? Why is $u$ a group element ?

Comment: @PULITAANDREA I've expanded the proof.

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for your help !